# I am trying to install this into my Emacs config

Tags: org-mode, load-path, load

I am trying to add this `org-download` into my Emacs config so I can paste images into my buffer. I tried following the steps but keeps telling me

```
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, org-download`

https://github.com/abo-abo/org-download
```

Please guide me. I am new to this. I am aware of the config file in Emacs. I am using org mode. I am also on windows 10.

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate, but I don't have time now to look for it. Search for `[load]` or `[load-path]`. (Is that directory in your `load-path`?)

Comment: Did you install the package? Do you know about the [emacs package system](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html)? If not, you might want to start there. Once the package is installed, then you can "follow the steps" (incidentally, what step are you following? Adding that information to your question would make it much easier to answer).

Comment: If it's a question about your `load-path`, as @Drew suggests, try [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63247/how-do-i-permanently-change-my-emacs-load-path) answer.

Comment: Is there a guide that teaches how one can install a package in emacs? I am not familiar with the steps. Please help.

Comment: Yes, I linked to it above. You can also search for `emacs configure package` both on Emacs SE and on the Web in general and probably get hundreds of hits. I would start at the [Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InstallingPackages).